# if and else statement is not working in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my jquery function. I can get the correct value in success
when i use the value in if and else statements it does not work

```js
function retrieveData() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://localhost/DB/login.php',
    data: {
      email: $("#email").val(),
      pass: $("#pass").val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var response = data;

      if (response == 'Employee') {
        window.location.href = "#employees_details";
      } else if (response == 'Employer') {
        window.location.href = "#job_details";
      } else {
        alert(error);
      }
    }
  });
  //this is mandatory other wise your from will be submitted.
  return false;

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate eon exactly what you mean by 'it doesn't work'. What does it do? What should it do? Are there any errors in the console? Also note that your `return response` in the `retrieveData()` function is redundant as the AJAX call is asynchronous. If you want to stop the form submission call `preventDefault()` on the submit event that's raised before this function is called.

Comment: what response is thrown when you run the ajax call try to `alert(data)` or `console.log(data)` inside the `success` function.

Comment: plus you have an error in your code you cannot return the response, if you are using form submit and want to prevent the default behavior you should use `return false` instead;

Comment: it gives the value of Employee

Comment: Well it obviously doesn't, or your code would work. Try adding a call to `trim()` to remove any whitespace around the value.

Comment: if the response is `Employee` try verifying if there are no white spaces along with the text as you are trying to compare the text `if (response == 'Employee') {`

Comment: function retrieveData() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://localhost/DB/login.php',
    data: {
      email: $("#email").val(),
      pass: $("#pass").val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var response = data;

      if (response == 'Employee') {
        window.location.href = "#employees_details";
      } else if (response == 'Employer') {
        window.location.href = "#job_details";
      } else {
        alert(error);
      }
    }
  });
  //this is mandatory other wise your from will be submitted.
  return false;

}

Comment: Please use the `edit` link under your question to add code. It's unreadable in comments

Comment: i have tried that but it still does not work

Comment: use alert like this `alert('"'+data+'"');` in the success and see if there are white spaces after or before the double quotes

Comment: Please tell us more than 'it doesn't work'! That's useless information.

Comment: Thanks for your answers the problem was with the white spaces